# Is the matrix $A = I - \frac{J}{n+1}$ idempotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

I am supposed to figure out if the following statement is false or true.

> If $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix, and $J$ is an  $n \times n$ matrix consisting entirely of ones, then the matrix $$A = I - \frac{J}{n+1}$$ is idempotent (i.e., $A^{2} = A$).

---

I understand obviously what $I$ and $J$ are, my issue is with the $A = I - \frac{J}{n+1}$. I searched my textbook and found no reference to it. What does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The expression $A = I - \frac{J}{n+1}$ is matrix addition, where $\frac{J}{n+1}$ represents scalar multiplication of the matrix $J$ by $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Since the matrix $J$ consists completely of $1$s, each entry of the scaled matrix $\frac{J}{n+1}$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$. Here is the matrix addition:

$$ I - \frac{J}{n+1} =
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
-
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1} \\
\frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1} \\
\end{array}\right]$$

$$ \implies A = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{n}{n+1} & \frac{-1}{n+1} & \cdots & \frac{-1}{n+1} \\
\frac{-1}{n+1} & \frac{n}{n+1} & \cdots & \frac{-1}{n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac{-1}{n+1} & \frac{-1}{n+1} & \cdots & \frac{n}{n+1} \\
\end{array}\right] $$

An interesting matrix. You could describe it by $A_{ij}=\frac{n}{n+1}$ if $i=j$ and $A_{ij}=\frac{-1}{n+1}$ if $i\neq j$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response!

Answer (score 2):

It is not hard to manually obtain $J^2=nJ$. Now it's just a matter of some matrix algebra:

$$A^2=(I-\frac{1}{n+1}J)^2=I^2-\frac{1}{n+1}IJ-\frac{1}{n+1}JI+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}J^2 = \\
= I - \frac{2}{n+1}J + \frac{n}{(n+1)^2}J = I + \frac{n-2(n+1)}{(n+1)^2}J = \\
= I + \frac{-n-2}{(n+1)^2}J = I - \frac{1}{n+1}J - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}J = A - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}J \neq A$$

As you can see, $A$ is not idempotent.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give me a detailed response!

Comment: Please take another look at your arithmetic between the last term on line 2 and the first term on line 3.  Also, OP's question was about what the matrix expression meant.  OP did not, in fact, ask for the solution to his/her homework problem.

Comment: One of the eigenvectors of the symmetric matrix $A$ is the all-ones vector, with eigenvalue $1 - n/(n+1)$. It can't be idempotent.

Comment: @HermitianCrustacean Thank you. I've fixed the answer. As pointed out, the matrix isn't idempotent. Since there is already an accepted answer on the actual question, I'll leave mine for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @HermitianCrustacean In the title of the question, OP *did* implicitly ask about the problem itself and not just about the meaning of a term in the problem. OP could perhaps have chosen a better title and not bothered to supply details which are not relevant for the specific question about the notation (if that was their sole question).